# error TS2339: Property 'PRE' does not exist on type 'ApiResponse'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to retrieve data from a webService. I can share the JSON structure with you.

```
   "PRE":[
      {
         "DEPO":979534429484,
         "CLER":"RC3038",
         "INTITULE1":"PORTEFEUILLE RC3038",
         "PHONE":"0999999999999",
         "TOMANY":"FALSE",
         "PREPTF":[
            {
               "NUM":146662,
               "CLER":"RC3038",
               "SVM":94533166,
               "ISIN":"BE0945331669",
               "LABEL":"ARKIMEDES FONDS",
               "QUANTITE":10.00,
               "DATE":"2012-04-18",
               "TYPE":"IN",
               "PERSONNE_CONTACT":"",
               "CONTREPARTIE":"DEXIA",
               "TEL":0,
               "FAX":0,
               "STATUT":9,
               "STATUT_LIB":"Fait",
               "REF_ALPHA":"CO12240000048563",
               "REF_RBC":"",
               "TRADE_DATE":"2012-04-18",
               "VALUE_DATE":"2012-04-19",
               "TRAITEMENT_DATE":"2012-04-18",
               "ANNULATION_DATE":"0001-01-01",
               "RECEPTION_DATE":"2012-04-25",
               "REM1":"",
               "REM2":"",
               "COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT":160.100000,
               "ACHAT_DATE":"0001-01-01",
               "PMBIS":"N",
               "TIS":0.000000,
               "CHANGEMENT_BENEF_ECO":"O"
            }
         ]
      },

   ]
```

I don't know if the structure of the interface seems correct to you?

```
export interface TransferResponse extends ApiResponse {
  PRE: PreTransfer[];
}

export interface PreTransfer {
  DEPO: number;
  CLER: string;
  INTITULE1: string;
  PHONE: string;
  TOMANY: string;
  PREPTF: {
    NUM: number;
    CLER: string;
    SVM: number;
    ISIN: string;
    LABEL: string;
    QUANTITE: number;
    DATE: string;
    TYPE: string;
    PERSONNE_CONTACT: string;
    CONTREPARTIE: string;
    TEL: number;
    FAX: number;
    STATUT: number;
    STATUT_LIB: string;
    REF_ALPHA: string;
    REF_RBC: string;
    TRADE_DATE: string;
    VALUE_DATE: string;
    TRAITEMENT_DATE: string;
    ANNULATION_DATE: string;
    RECEPTION_DATE: string;
    REM1: string;
    REM2: string;
    COURS_MOYEN_ACHAT: number;
    ACHAT_DATE: string;
    PMBIS: string;
    TIS: number;
    CHANGEMENT_BENEF_ECO: string;
  }[];
}
```

Then, I'm trying to create the method that will allow me to retrieve the data from the webservice.

```
customerTransfers: PreTransfer;

overviewTransfers(account: string): void {
  this.service.overviewTransfers(account).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
  ).subscribe(res => {
    this.customerTransfers = res.PRE.map(val => {
      return {
        

      }
    });

  });
}
```

I got this error message:

```
error TS2339: Property 'PRE' does not exist on type 'ApiResponse'.

67     this.customerTransfers = res.PRE.map(val => {
```

I don't understand what's wrong, I followed a tutorial.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what the service sends, maybe the PRE is in a data object ? Try to console log res

Comment: I see data `data -> {RETURNCODE: 'OKK00', PRE: Array(88), RETURNLIST: Array(0)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say for sure, I need to look at the `overviewTransfers` method of your service. But since you didn't share it, I can assume that it says that it returns an `Observable<ApiResponse>` type (maybe implicitly, if you did not specified it), based on the text of the error. Most likely, there really are no such fields *declared (not presented in fact in runtime)* as `PRE` in `ApiResponse`. If so, the more precise type should be specified as return type of the `overviewTransfers` method: `Observable<TransferResponse>`.

In addition, I noticed that the `customerTransfers` field is typed as `PreTransfer`, although, judging by the name and what is assigned to it, it is an array and should be typed as `PreTransfer[]`.